# Excel return blank on Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to cross reference 2 tables, but I got duplicate result on every entries that has no corresponding entries on another table..

For example, this is the result page.

[image: result table]

I am using

`=VLOOKUP([@mbox];Table2; 2)`

for the above table.

And this below is the source table.

[image: source reference table]

I have searched, and as far as my search went, it should return #N/A, correct? I need it to return #N/A so that I know which account has been deleted, and not its duplicate like this.

Thank you

Comment: You want an exact match,  right?  If so, add the 4th parameter `0` to Vlookup

Comment: Yes.. let me try

Comment: @chrisneilsen lol.. it was that simple.. stupid me. Thank you.. can you put as answer? So I can accept.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, while `VLOOKUP` is fine to use. It's noteworthy that the `INDEX`+`MATCH` combination is equally fast at least and significantly faster at best.

Comment: Another benefit of Index Match is the ability to return values to the left of the match.  And another is that it doesn't matter if you're matching rows or columns.  And another is the introduction to Index Match Match.  Though, to be fair, Index Match does require a 0 at the end just like Vlookup.